# crontab adding carriage returns

Tags: cron, carriage-return

I'm using a script to add multiple cronjobs to users at the same time like so:

```
sed -e "s/\[\[USER\]\]/$user/g" $file > /home/deploy/cronjobScripts/tmp
crontab -u $user "/home/deploy/cronjobScripts/tmp"
crontab -u $user -l
```

$file points to a path with the template cronjob file.

But after crontab adds it to a user, it adds ^M to every line (carriage return in vim) which breaks the commands it has to execute.

Why does crontab do this and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Are you sure those characters are not already contained inside the remporary file you create? DIfferent linebreak encodings on different operating systems?

Comment: Yes I'm quite sure, with vim you can use :set list to see newlines and I can clearly see the \r being added in /var/spool/cron/crontab/$user and not in the $file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arkascha was right after all, it seems that \r\n was present but vim did not show it.

When I used `cat -vE /home/deploy/cronjobScripts/tmp` it showed the `\r` after removing those with dos2unix the cronjobs worked perfectly

Comment: dos2unix did it for me on Windows! I should have known since I was already using dos2unix for some other files but the "bad minute" message kept throwing me off.